# What are "Code Styles" in Intelli J IDEs?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I took a look at [this](https://github.com/square/java-code-styles), and I thought it was a color scheme or something. I followed my stems to find out that **it's not**.

What are "Code Styles" and what changes can they, for example, do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code styles dictate what happens when you auto-format your code, which includes:

- The placing of braces, forcing or omitting their inclusion with a single statement
- The amount of spaces indentation does
- Whether or not you chop down or wrap long statements or parameters
- How annotations appear in fields (on top of/next to)
- Whether or not you use `import *` statements in Java, and what/when the cutoff is
- How you close ML tags (XML, HTML, etc - either with the `</full-name>` or `<full-name />`)
- ...and many other pieces.

Code style varies from person to person, and shop to shop, so having IntelliJ as a way to configure this once and shared with others is ideal.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. Just a question, when I want to initialize a class called `DatabaseReference` for example, usually the dropdown menu gives me an option for its name to be `databaseReference`. Can I give it a custom name like `database` so it suggests it autocompletes the name to `database`?

Comment: Don't think so.  Autocomplete only really works in the context of symbols that already exist.